# Why is the Scipy instance of expon() returning type: <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen>

Tags: scipy, exponential-distribution, frozenset

I am interested why the code below returns an instance type of `rv_frozen` when `expon()` is an instance of `class expon_gen(rv_continuous)` in the `stats._continous_distns.py` file.

Shouldn't it return type: `<scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_continous>`?

```py
In [1]: from scipy.stats import expon

In [2]: type(expon())
Out[2]: scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a distribution instance (backets in `expon()`) freezes a distribution.

Here freezing means fixing the values of the shape parameters. Trivial for expon, less so for e.g. gamma and such.